# A php script that automatic fill a form and submit it with POST

Tags: php, forms, post, submit

I apologies for my bad english....

Is there possible to modify this HTML code for it retrieve the data from POST method??

that page is only a input and a submit button, in there possible to include php code in, for it receive his input by POST and then automatic submit??

I know it's possible with javascript but I need it in php POST...

thank you very much for your help :)

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>title</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form method="post" action="send.php" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <input name="avatar" type="file">
        <input name="envoyer" value="Envoyer" type="submit">
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: PHP is executed on the (web-)server, javascript by the client (browser). if you need the submit to come from the client, then it has to be in javascript.

Answer (score -1):

No there is no possibility of wht u want. PHP code is executable only on server side. So, anyhow you have to create a seperate PHP script file and send your form to it for further posting.

Comment: There *is* a way to do it, a PHP script could "reverse-engineer" the form and detect the fields presents by parsing the HTML in it. That's in fact what the testing library of the Laravel framework does. See [the documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/testing#interacting-with-your-application) for an example.